# Using Themes in Android

Tags: java, android, themes, settings, android-preferences

Im trying to switch between Holo.Light and Holo (Dark) so everything in my application is changed to the theme the user sets in the preferences.

I've been looking at a few open source apps that this is done in and cant seem to make it work with my project, Any help on this would be greately appreciated.

The Current ISSUE im running into inside DashboardActivity.java is:

*"I've having issues with "setTheme(Integer.parseInt( pref.getString("*

### DashboardActivity (Updated)

```
public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {

public static final int THEME_BLACK = R.style.DarkThemeAndroid;
public static final int THEME_WHITE = R.style.LightThemeAndroid;
public static final int THEME_WHITE_BLACK = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_DarkActionBar;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // I've having issue with the "pref.getString" i've tried "Settings.getString" and get error about needing a getString method is needed in Settings.java
    setTheme(Integer.parseInt( pref.getString("selectedTheme", String.valueOf(R.style.LightThemeAndroid) )));
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard_layout);
          // the rest of my code
      )
    )
```

### Settings (Updated)

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity implements
    OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

final static String[] mThemeEntries = {
    "Default (Light)", 
    "Dark"
    };
final static String[] mThemeValues = {  
    String.valueOf(R.style.LightThemeAndroid), 
    String.valueOf(R.style.DarkThemeAndroid)
    };
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Loads the XML preferences file.
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
//  SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


    ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference)findPreference("selectedTheme");

    listPref.setEntries(mThemeEntries);
    listPref.setEntryValues(mThemeValues);

    listPref.setValue( pref.getString("selectedTheme", String.valueOf(mThemeValues[0]) ) );
```

XML Resources

Themes.xml

```
 <style name="LightThemeAndroid" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"> 
   </style>         

 <style name="DarkThemeAndroid" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
   </style>
```

Settings.xml

```
  <ListPreference
android:title="Themes"
android:summary="Change the UI of the application"
android:key="theme"
android:entries="@array/themesReturnValue"
android:entryValues="@array/themesDisplayWord" 
android:defaultValue="Theme1" />
```

Arrays.xml

```
 <string-array name="themesReturnValue">
   <item>Light</item>
    <item>Dark</item>
    <item>LightActionBar</item>
         </string-array>   
<string-array name="themesDisplayWord">
    <item>Theme1</item>
    <item>Theme2</item>
    <item>Theme3</item>
        </string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getTheme()` is a non-static method and you are trying to call it in a static way (not from an instance variable). You need an instance of the object to call the non-static method. Also, the docs state

> Note that this should be called before any views are instantiated in the Context (for example before calling setContentView(View) or inflate(int, ViewGroup)).

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#getTheme%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

There exists non-static getTheme() method of the **ContextThemeWrapper** class that returns Theme object type. Change the name of the getTheme() method to a different one for example getThe() and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

First like codeMagic said, you are calling getTheme in a non-static way, I would also put the theme related constants in 1 class. Try making getTheme a static method (Although i would probably create a seperate class just for theme). Apart from that, here is a solution I was working on 2 days ago as i couldn't find anywhere on google or here for an answer to a more dynamic fluid theme preference.

I start off with my preference fragment (in your case, activity). Then declare the themes and values into an array...

```
public class LayoutFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

final static String[] mThemeEntries = {
    "Default (Light)", 
    "Dark"
    };
final static String[] mThemeValues = {  
    String.valueOf(R.style.Theme_Default), 
    String.valueOf(R.style.Theme_Dark)
    };
```

then in my oncreate method, i set these values (note, in the xml i do not set these values and there are no references to those values in the xml files)

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                 
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_layout);
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

    ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference)findPreference("selectedTheme");

    listPref.setEntries(mThemeEntries);
    listPref.setEntryValues(mThemeValues);

    listPref.setValue( pref.getString("selectedTheme", String.valueOf(mThemeValues[0]) ) );

}
```

Notice that i had converted these values to a string, dont ask why, but i was getting a whole lot of trouble trying to store the int value of those resource id's (this is also why xml values was not an option)...

now when ever i need to set a theme from the user preference... I just call

```
setTheme(Integer.parseInt( pref.getString("selectedTheme", String.valueOf(R.style.Theme_Default) )));
```

and off course you could provide a static method somewhere to do the castings etc without writing it for each activity.

EDIT: You don't need the array's to be static, I must off left them like that while I was trying different things to get it to work.

Comment: I've updated some of my code above, I thank you so much for helping me with this, However im still having some trouble's, Can you look at my above code and see where i went array.

Comment: Try removing, entries, entryValues and defaultEntry from your settings xml. Is there any errors raised that is stopping it from compiling? You should also change the values too match your environment... eg, (ListPreference)findPreference("selectedTheme"); should be (ListPreference)findPreference("theme");